# How to find Min and Max within the group in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to find a DAX formula to show in the card to display the season range between the year and week. I want to get the min week in the min year and max week and max year :

I have the below table:

[image]

I want to show the card like below:
"Between 2020-33 and 2021-1"

But the below formula shows as :
"Between 2020-1 and 2021-52"

Can anyone please help me to find the DAX to show the correct card?

My current formula is like below:

```
Min_Season =
CALCULATE (
    MIN ( 'Year-Week_Table'[Year] ),
    FILTER ( 'Flag-Year-Week_Table', 'Flag-Year-Week_Table'[STD_CY_Ind] = 1 )
) & "-"
    & CALCULATE (
        MIN ( 'Year-Week_Table'[Week] ),
        FILTER ( 'Flag-Year-Week_Table', 'Flag-Year-Week_Table'[STD_CY_Ind] = 1 )
    ) & " and "
    & CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'Year-Week_Table'[Year] ),
        FILTER ( 'Flag-Year-Week_Table', 'Flag-Year-Week_Table'[STD_CY_Ind] = 1 )
    ) & "-"
    & CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'Year-Week_Table'[Week] ),
        FILTER ( 'Flag-Year-Week_Table', 'Flag-Year-Week_Table'[STD_CY_Ind] = 1 )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

The DAX is calculating the min/max of year where flag = 1 and then independently the min/max of week where flag = 1, which is why the result is "Between 2020-1 and 2021-52".

You really want the min/max of the combination of Year and Month combined, not independently (e.g. for the first row 2020-33).  You can achieve this by combining the columns first with

```
Year-Week = 'Flag-Year-Week_Table'[Year] & "-" & 'Flag-Year-Week_Table'[Week]
```

and then alter your DAX to consider the min/max of the new column

```
Min_Season = 
    CALCULATE 
    (
        MIN ('Flag-Year-Week_Table'[Year-Week]), 
        FILTER ( 'Flag-Year-Week_Table', 'Flag-Year-Week_Table'[Season Flag] = 1  )
        
    )
    & " and "  & 
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'Flag-Year-Week_Table'[Year-Week] ),

        FILTER ( 'Flag-Year-Week_Table', 'Flag-Year-Week_Table'[Season Flag] = 1  )
    )
```

giving you the result of

[image]